# Devenv Commandline Build not using C# 7.2 language feature

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-7.2

After upgrading to c# 7.2, our automated build server kicked a compile error. 
"Features 'readonly references' is not available in c#7.0. Please use language 7.2 or greater."

The project that is failing is set to use "latest minor version", which is 7.2, in the advanced build tab. The project builds and runs fine in visual studio. The command line fails with that error. Setting the build setting explicitly to 7.2 instead of "latest minor version" also fails.

Why is the command line failing to load the latest language feature? And it works in the VS ide?

The command line is
"devenv SolutionFile.sln /Build Release"

The sample application to reproduce/demonstrate this is a WPF app, with a form and a button, and a handler to pass a struct.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private struct Test123
        {
            public string test;
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Test123 test;
            test.test = "foo";
            Test(test);
        }

        private void Test(in Test123 test)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
```

[image]

Update:
Also, there is a mismatching version in the commandline. The commandline opens and says it is on v15.5.1. However, the devenv exe gives an earlier version.
[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with the automated build, so please add some details about what how your build server is setup..

Comment: @DanLing
Hi Dan, Sorry for the confusion. It has nothing do with the automated build. Open a command prompt and typing in the commandline I specified in the original post reproduces the error.

I added a picture of the command line if that helps.

Comment: Can you run `where devenv` to make sure your path is running the correct version of VS?

Comment: @DanLing Yes, I checked that before (and should have included). Both the Ide shortcut (that works for build) and command line claim to be pointing at the same location. Inside MS visual studio directory @... Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Also, I only have VS 2017 installed, no earlier major release version exists. This version of vs2017 was also a fresh reinstall from MS page.

Comment: Hmm. Does release build work from the UI as well?

Comment: @DanLing

Yes, release and debug work the same. (I just double checked with the sample app of code posted above).

Comment: Try specifying the full path to proper "devenv" or "msbuild", to confirm that works?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to verify that C# 7.2 is being enabled is to edit the csproj file directly, and make sure `<LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>` is included in all your build configurations.

For example, release configuration should look like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  <LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Yes, my project file looks like:
  <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
In the IDE, this renders as "C# latest minor version (latest)"
The IDE builds, the command line does not.